# tracing an email address with out receiving an email from the subject

Tags: email

Is it possible for someone to trace you or get your IP address and info needed to track you if they have your email address but have never received or got hold of an actual email from you? If so how can they do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can send them an email and embed an IP tracking "image" into the email.

There's a lot of websites providing this service.

This will of course work only if they open the email.

Comment: This now makes more sense :)

Comment: @Samuel there is no guarantee this will work, as most mail clients will initially block images, for this reason

Comment: It can work, with some creativity :)

Comment: (meaning a reason to display remote content)

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like your question is the opposite of Samuel's answer. It sounds like you're asking:

"Given an person's email address, with passive efforts only, is it possible to determine the subject's IP address and/or location?"

If that's the case then the answer is: Kind of. You'll be able to get some information by resolving the mx records of the mail server and doing some recon of the DNS (i.e., whois registrant info) but to get an individual account's information, it's going to be more difficult.